# How to get PCs IP for WakeOnLan over internet (only by using stock Windows 7 applications)

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, wake-on-lan

I want to wake a Windows 7 PC over LAN (via internet).
To find out its IP I don't want to use an external application (like dyndns).

So I only want to use what Windows already offers.

Is that possible?

If not it would be ok to run a command-line application whenever necessary but not all the time.

Comment: Wake-On-Lan typically uses the Mac address of the network card, not the IP (00:00:00:00 hex format instead of 000.000.000.000 numerical)

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use DynDNS?

Comment: Well I could use it, but can't reconfigure the router to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to wake-on-lan from over the internet directly, as wake-on-lan doesn't operate with TCP/IP. You will need a host inside your LAN that can send the appropriate packet.

However, there is no way around using DynDNS or a static IP - that is the *only* way to contact your network from the rest of the internet; That's like trying to find a building in a foreign country without having its street address! You could always find out the IP while you're at the computer and then memorize it and hope it doesn't change, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: OK then how to update a DynDNS or whatever from within that PC without using extra software. The only problem I see is when the PC was off for some time and can't update the dyndns.

Comment: It *could* be done over the Internet, provided you send the magic packet over UDP (to the external address) and somehow configure your router to rebroadcast it to the entire LAN.

Comment: In this scenario I can't alter any router settings.

Comment: You will at very least have to reconfigure it to allow you to connect into a machine on your LAN remotely, either via SSH or remote desktop or similar. And you can download and run a DynDNS updater from any PC on your network which will update the DynDNS account with your current IP.

Comment: DynDNs can be updated from within the network using a scheduled script on the target PC.